# Application.Goto Looping

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a function that copies values from one spreadsheet and pastes them into another for analysis purposes. Everything up to "US_CAD_EquipCharges1" works, but then I receive a Run-Time Error 1004 "That command cannot be used on multiple selections".

Below is the code and I cannot figure out what this means.

```
Sub CrewRates()

    Application.Goto reference:="CAD_NU_CrewRates"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.Goto reference:="US_NU_CrewRates"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("E4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Sheets("_6a_US_CAD_Conventional").Select
    Application.Goto reference:="NDE_Regions"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.Goto reference:="US_CAD_EquipCharges1"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.Goto reference:="US_CAD_EquipCharges2"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.Goto reference:="US_CAD_EquipCharges3"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Sheets("_6a_US_CAD_Conventional").Select
    Application.Goto reference:="NDE_Regions"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


    Call VendorNames
        Columns("A:H").Select
        Columns("A:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit


End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you selecting the same range in the same sheet 3 times in a row?

Comment: Are you trying to change tabs by doing Application.Goto reference:="US_CAD_EquipCharges1"

Comment: @davidg I have three separate named ranges because the data set itself has over 1000 rows and I am only trying to evaluate 6 of them among 12 different suppliers.

Comment: @HarshSingh but you're pasting all 3 US_CAD_EquipCarges to cell I4 of sheet Summary. It will only take the third, will it not? You're pasting over your cell 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume that `"US_CAD_EquipCharges1"` is a named range made up of desperate ranges on a sheet.

It is not possible to copy a range that is made up of smaller desperate ranges which are different sizes e.g. one block is 3 rows and the other is 5 rows. To avoid the error you need to adjust the named range so that it is a single block of cells.

I have a named range called ourRangeX which is defined as this =Sheet3!$F$8:$G$11,Sheet3!$J$6:$K$8

This runs ok

```
Sub foo2()
Range("ourRangeX").Select
End Sub
```

This fails

```
Sub bar2()
Range("ourRangeX").Select
Range("ourRangeX").Copy
End Sub
```

Can you edit the named range `US_CAD_EquipCharges2` so that it complies to the above rule?

Comment: @MatthewD - yes that is very interesting: I just tested and a union's range will copy but a named range made up of two disperate blacks will not copy ... strange behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the response. US_CAD_EquipCharges2 is a subset over the overall data set, which is over 1000 rows. I think Name Ranges is limited to a certain number of rows and I reached that limit. I am trying to avoid manual errors by copying and pasting these rows into a separate data set. Hope this makes sense.